# CronJob in Shopware Plugin

Tags: php, cron, shopware

I want to register a PHP function as a cronjob in Shopware.I am struggling to figure out how to do this, tbh I find the Shopware documentation light... ( to say the least ).

All I could find until now is an answer by Alexey Palamar suggesting to
create a custom component and that it is possible to call it as a cronjob and he gave the following 2 lines :

```
      $component = ShopwarePlugins\PluginName\Components\CustomComponent(); 
      $component->doSync();
```

Not having an extensive Shopware knowledge I am wondering how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

This works in Shopware 5:

1) Create a component which will execute your cronjob and implements SubscriberInterface:

```
<?php

use Enlight\Event\SubscriberInterface;

namespace MyPlugin\Subscribers;
class ProductDataImportSubscriber implements SubscriberInterface
{

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Shopware_CronJob_ProductDataImport' => 'onDataImport'
        ];
    }

    public function onDataImport(\Shopware_Components_Cron_CronJob $job)
    {
        return $this->dataImport();
    }
...
}
```

2) Register this class in `<YourPlugin>/Resources/services.xml`

```
...
<service id="my_plugin.subscribers.product_data_import_subscriber" class="MyPlugin\Subscribers\ProductDataImportSubscriber">
            <tag name="shopware.event_subscriber"/>
        </service>
...
```

3) Define your cronjob in `<YourPlugin>/Resources/cronjob.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cronjobs xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../engine/Shopware/Components/Plugin/schema/cronjob.xsd">

    <cronjob>
        <name>Import products</name>
        <action>Shopware_CronJob_ProductDataImport</action>
        <active>true</active>
        <interval>60</interval>
        <disableOnError>false</disableOnError>
    </cronjob>
</cronjobs>
```

4) Install or Update your plugin in Shopware Backend > Configuration > Plugin Manager

5) Starting your CronJob: open in browser http://mywebshop.com:8080/backend/cron

6) Optional, if you want to execute it regularily base on your schedule: Once yo have created such a Shopware CronJob, you need some external trigger to tell Shopware you want to evaluate configured CronJobs and run those in plan.
In other words, you need to set up a [Unix Cron job](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/) which executes regularily (e.g. every 30 minutes) a simple script with one command, like:

```
./<path_to_shopware>/bin/console sw:cron:run
```

if you need to trigger Shopware CronJobs evaluation from a remote server, you can put into your script:

```
curl http(s)://<myShopwareDomainOrIP>:<shopwarePort>/backend/cron
```

e.g. `curl http://mywebshop.com:8080/backend/cron`

this is the best way i have found so far

Comment: Please add some further information to your answer: how does all this help to create a custom cronjob?

Comment: @NicoHase: thanks Nico for your comment, i did not realize in my first post that you cannot find any documentation on how to create a cronjob from scratch in Shopware, meanwhile i have checked the docu and cannot find it either, fortunately i use Shopware a lot nowadays and remeber well how to do it ;)